# Find all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\gcd(3n-2,n+7)=1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, divisibility, proof-explanation

> Find all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\gcd(3n-2,n+7)=1$.

I think that we cannot use directly Bézout or Euclidean division. So let $d$ a non trivial common divisor of $3n-2$ and $n+7$. Using linear combination we obtain that $d \mid (-23)$.

If $d=\pm 23$ then there exists $k,k'$ integers such that $3n-2=\pm23k$ and $n+7=\pm 23k'$, so $3n-2=\pm23k$ and $n=\pm23k'-7$, so $\pm69k'-23=\pm23k=3n-2.$ (Is this transition correct ?)

If $n=\pm23k-7$ we have that $23$ divides $3n-2$. That's why we have to exclude all the $n$ of that form.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: [`Resultant[3n-2,n+7,n]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Resultant%5B3n-2,n%2B7,n%5D) gives $23$.

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty much correct (the answer set is $23k-7$; while you state $23k+7$ you previously describe numbers of the form $23k-7$, so I assume that's a typo).

Just a note, though: since $d$ is a divisor, we may assume it's positive $23$, which simplifies the equations. Thus, the answer form can be listed as excluding everything that's $23k-7$ for a $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, which is simpler than $\pm 23 k-7$ for a $k\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: Thank you but the fact is that in the system of the two equations I have $k$ and $k'$ and I just have $\pm69k'-23=23k$

Comment: It seems that $k$ or $k'$ is useless for the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

We need $$(3(n+7)-(3n-2),n+7)=1$$ or
$$(23,n+7)=1.$$
I hope now it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

Suffice to observe that $3(n+7)-(3n-2)=23$. So if $a \mid (n+7) $ and $a \mid (3n-2)$ then $a \mid 23$.
This gives $ n \equiv 16 \pmod{23}$. So $ \gcd(n+7, 3n-2)=1$ provided $ n \neq 16 \pmod{23}$.